The physics of swimming
How does the straight leg flutter kick provide propulsion for a swimmer?  The mechanical symmetry seems to preclude generation of a net force.

well, your legs are not straight is part of it...

You mean, the bent knees play a crucial part?  Maybe, but it isn't obvious.

The knees bending at the appropriate point in the kick cycle is definitely crucial. And note that swimmers are somewhat infamous for hyperextending their knees as well. I would suggest watching some YouTube videos of, say, Michael Phelps swimming freestyle from an underwater camera and watch (in slow motion if possible) how all the different parts of the body move throughout a kick cycle.

But still, how does it generate net forward propulsion?  The movement looks symmetrical.

As a long-time competitive swimmer, the movement and muscle forces are far from symmetrical. Lets take the down beat - the knee drops some and hyperextends with the foot back. As the lower leg descends the foot rotates as the knee straightens.  The force on the water is the foot sweeping water backwards. Hold your arm out straight from your body with palm up. Now bend the elbow and pull the palm by bending your wrist to you, like signaling someone backing up toward you. Now whip the hand forward and rotate it as you straighten the elbow back out. That is propulsion.

The up beat starts with the palm extended backwards as far as it goes, and your arm below vertical in front of you. As you raise the arm back up, you again rotate the palm towards you as you bend at the elbow. Again, the rotation of the hand pushes water away from you, providing the thrust. It is all in the timing of the relative motions of the joints.

Interesting.  I read something, some time ago, which advocated pulling the arm in a corkscrew fashion, like a propeller.
